# Count the number of documents of a type in index against a second index

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch, assume that I have two indices `my_users` and `user_actions`. Furthermore, assume that some of my users have a field `vipID`. I want to count the number of user actions of type `climb` that we carried out by users that have (a non-empty) `vipID` field.

On one hand, I know how to filter the users that have the `vipID` field:

```
curl localhost:8080/my_users/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "vipID"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

On the other hand, I know how to find all the climb actions carried out by user 1 and 2 (i.e. has `userID` field that equals either `1` or `2`):

```
curl localhost:8080/users_actions/climb/_search
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "adUserId": [
            "1",
            "2"
          ]
        }
      },
      "boost": 1.2
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know how to do both? How can I plug into the second query the `asUserId` from the first query.

### Edit:

The above is merely a minimal example. Based on the comment I scripted the task. However, in the real case, I have thousands of users and I get an `Argument list too long` error from `curl`.

Comment: The way can be, do the first query get userId, and execute second query. There is no another way of doing this with elasticsearch.

Comment: Doesn't sound too efficient. So it has to be a 2-phase process; first save the IDs of the users that have `vipID` and then pass it to the second query. If the 1st query involves `scroll`, does it change something?

Comment: Looks like your user_actions should be set up as child documents for my_users, then you can query them in one go.

Comment: @Dror, it isn't but, it is the wayaround, unless you think of unnecessary relationship between documents. I think, do aggregation at first and get ids, and apply the filter(in second). No it doesn't change any (in any case). Believe me, we are doing it for a year...

Answer (score 0):

In the mapping for `my_users`, specify `user_actions` as child documents. Index them with `userID` as `parentID`. Then you can have a query on parent and filter the results with `has_child` filter. Something like this:

```
curl localhost:8080/my_users/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "and": [
               {
                  "exists": {
                     "field": "vipID"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "has_child": {
                     "type": "user_actions",
                     "query": {
                        "constant_score": {
                           "filter": {
                              "terms": {
                                 "adUserId": [
                                    "1",
                                    "2"
                                 ]
                              }
                           },
                           "boost": 1.2
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```